# Java 7 trigger heap dump without having JDK installed

Tags: java, java-7, heap-dump

How can I trigger a heap dump for a Java 7 VM running on Linux without having a JDK installed?

In earlier versions of Java it was possible to set the `-XX:+HeapDumpOnCtrlBreak` JVM option and then trigger a heap dump by using `kill -QUIT <pid>`.  I have been unable to get this to work with Java 7.  Is there an equivalent to this without needing the JDK installed to get JVisualVM or jmap.

Comment: Does `-XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError` work for you? http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/clopts-139448.html#gbzrr

Comment: As far as I am aware that still works (and we have it configured). We aren't actually getting to the point of running out of memory before our application is misbehaving. Therefore we would like to be able to trigger the heap dump on demand for analysis.

Comment: Do you get the error message `Unrecognized VM option 'HeapDumpOnCtrlBreak'`?

Comment: `HeapDumpOnCtrlBreak` is not listed at http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/tech/vmoptions-jsp-140102.html#DebuggingOptions

Comment: can you manage to hook jvisualvm to the process?

Comment: JVisualVM should work, but we want to be able to do this in a production environment where we do not have a JDK installed.

Answer (score 0):

VM option `-XX:+HeapDumpOnCtrlBreak` is no longer listed at http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/tech/vmoptions-jsp-140102.html. So, I conclude that it's no longer supported.

From http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/tech/vmoptions-jsp-140102.html:

> Options that are specified with -XX are not stable and are subject to
>   change without notice.

Comment: Yeah, it definitely isn't supported anymore we got an error trying to specify it.  I was hoping there was a similar way to get a heap dump in place of it.

Answer (score 0):

You can generate a core dump with `gcore`, move it to another machine, and attach `jmap` to generate hprof file as described in [Core dump taken with gcore, jmap conversion to hprof file format fails with Error message](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9981080/core-dump-taken-with-gcore-jmap-conversion-to-hprof-file-format-fails-with-erro)

See also [accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9981498/33622).