# Unable to convert coredump to hprof

Tags: java, coredump, hprof, jmap

I have a core.31690 file which I want to convert to hprof. I tried: `jmap -dump:format=b,file=mydump.hprof /usr/bin/java core.31690` but I got the following:

```
Attaching to core core.31690 from executable /usr/bin/java, please wait...
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at sun.tools.jmap.JMap.runTool(JMap.java:179)
    at sun.tools.jmap.JMap.main(JMap.java:110)
Caused by: sun.jvm.hotspot.debugger.UnmappedAddressException
    at sun.jvm.hotspot.debugger.PageCache.checkPage(PageCache.java:208)
    at sun.jvm.hotspot.debugger.PageCache.getData(PageCache.java:63)
    at sun.jvm.hotspot.debugger.DebuggerBase.readBytes(DebuggerBase.java:217)
    at sun.jvm.hotspot.debugger.linux.LinuxDebuggerLocal.readCInteger(LinuxDebuggerLocal.java:482)
    at sun.jvm.hotspot.debugger.linux.LinuxAddress.getCIntegerAt(LinuxAddress.java:69)
    at sun.jvm.hotspot.utilities.CStringUtilities.getString(CStringUtilities.java:61)
    at sun.jvm.hotspot.HotSpotTypeDataBase.readVMTypes(HotSpotTypeDataBase.java:128)
    at sun.jvm.hotspot.HotSpotTypeDataBase.<init>(HotSpotTypeDataBase.java:85)
    at sun.jvm.hotspot.bugspot.BugSpotAgent.setupVM(BugSpotAgent.java:568)
    at sun.jvm.hotspot.bugspot.BugSpotAgent.go(BugSpotAgent.java:494)
    at sun.jvm.hotspot.bugspot.BugSpotAgent.attach(BugSpotAgent.java:348)
    at sun.jvm.hotspot.tools.Tool.start(Tool.java:169)
    at sun.jvm.hotspot.tools.HeapDumper.main(HeapDumper.java:77)
    ... 6 more
```

I tried looking online but couldn't find anything. Any pointers?

Comment: Do you use the same machine which you generated the core file on? I have some troubles while was doing this on different machines...

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9981080/core-dump-taken-with-gcore-jmap-conversion-to-hprof-file-format-fails-with-erro