# jmap [option] <executable <core> - what does that mean and how to use it?

Tags: java, jmap

I'm trying to use jmap utility.
It's too hard to specify pid each time, so I search for easier option.
In jmap's help I found an option

**jmap [option] < executable < core >**

But this absolutely not self-explanatory.
What stands for executable/core? How can I specify it ?  Haven't found any sample.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From the [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/tools/share/jmap.html):

> **executable**
>
> > Java executable from which the core dump was produced.
>
> **core**
>
> > core file for which the memory map is to be printed.

I agree, that is a bit *terse*...

The **core** is the *core dump* to get the heap from, and the **executable** is the *Java executable* the app that produced the core dump was run with

And [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9981080/core-dump-taken-with-gcore-jmap-conversion-to-hprof-file-format-fails-with-erro) provides an example of using it:

> ```
> jmap -dump:format=b,file=dump.hprof /usr/java/jdk1.6.0_16/bin/java core.dump.2878
> ```